# https://registry-1.docker.io/v2/": dial tcp: lookup registry-1.docker.io on [::1]:53: read udp [::1]:38297->[::1]:53: read: connection refused

Tags: docker, docker-registry, docker-network

I'm getting the following error, when I'm trying to build the docker image.

I tried to build the docker image and I tried restarting the docker with following commands.
systemctl restart docker

[https://registry-1.docker.io/v2/"](https://registry-1.docker.io/v2/%22): dial tcp: lookup registry-1.docker.io on [::1]:53: read udp [::1]:38297->[::1]:53: read: connection refusedd

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
sudo systemctl restart docker.service
sudo systemctl restart docker.socket
```

This two commands worked for me